# Commits History when merging repo as a remote subdirectory

Tags: git, github

I try to follow here [Git: Subtree Merge into a Deeply Nested Subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904256/git-subtree-merge-into-a-deeply-nested-subdirectory) to merge my local repo into a subdirectory of a remote repo `dir_all`, with 2 sublevel deep as my repo is `sub_dir_1` (which I want to be) under `dir_all/sub_dir_all`. The script goes as :

```
$ cd /path/to/dir_all
$ git remote add -f sub_dir_1_remote /path/to/sub_dir_1
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories sub_dir_1_remote/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=sub_dir_all/sub_dir_1 -u sub_dir_1_remote
$ git commit -m "Merge local project as our subdirectory"
$ git pull -s subtree sub_dir_1_remote
```

The scripts seem to go well and I can see all the individual commits history merging after the overall commit history if I use `git log`. However, when I uploaded it into github using

```
git push origin master
```

I cannot see the whole commit history if I clicked the History button but only the commits after I did the merge including the "merge" commit, but I could see the whole commits history if I clicked the `Commits` button. Why does this happen and what I should do to let `History` be consistent with what `commits` show as I think normally the `commits` should include directory `History` ?

Example : For repo https://github.com/huggingface/transformers, we see there are 4328 commits and in one of its subdirectory we can see its history https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/utils.